# installing rmarkdown packages gives me non-zero exit status

Tags: r-markdown

I am completely new to RStudio. Hence I apologize in advance for my inexpertise.
the response to `install.packages("rmarkdown")` the first code below.

Then, when I try to go to New file Rmarkdown it appears the alert: "Creating R Markdown documents requires an updated version of the rmarkdown package. Do you want to install this package now?"

When I accept I get the second code below.

What can I do to solve the problem? You help a total beginner please? Thank you for your patience. I am using RStudio 1.3.1093 on OS Sierra 10.12.6

'''

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rmarkdown    2.3    2.5             FALSE

installing the source package ‘rmarkdown’

provo con l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3203415 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/+VERSION': No such file or directory
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 51734 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     51735 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_3/fpj05lzj5zj03typ4t6k3wlh0000gn/T/RtmpMVE5wW/downloaded_packages’ 







Installing 'rmarkdown' for R Markdown...
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rmarkdown    2.3    2.5             FALSE
installing the source package ‘rmarkdown’

provo con l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3203415 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/+VERSION': No such file or directory
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 51767 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     51768 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/_3/fpj05lzj5zj03typ4t6k3wlh0000gn/T/RtmpDhf44F/downloaded_packages’


✔ Package 'rmarkdown' successfully installed.
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `install.packages(“rmarkdown”, dep = TRUE)` . I also see something about the time zone, is your PC on the right time? I’ve seen installs not work because of the pc had the wrong time. You will also need to install latex with Rmarkdown